# Capybara: cannot take screenshot with selenium driver on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

Here is my Capybara configuration:

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'

# Configure Capypara with javascript client
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
#Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome


# Take screenshot for every feature test failed
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each, :type => :feature) do |example|
    if example.exception
      meta = example.metadata
      name = "test-failure-#{File.basename(meta[:file_path])}-#{meta[:line_number]}.png"

      # Save screenshots in CI
      screenshot_root_path = ENV["CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS"] || Rails.root.join("tmp", "capybara")

      screenshot_path = [screenshot_root_path, 'feature_tests', name].join("/")

      page.save_screenshot(screenshot_path, full: true)
      puts  "Screenshot Taken: #{screenshot_path}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
 gem 'capybara'
 gem 'capybara-selenium'
```

But when a test failed, I cannot create screenshot. Please tell me how.

Comment: What is the issue? any exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can fix this now. I miss this line:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :headless_chrome
```

So the full setup should be:

```
# Configure Capypara with javascript client
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: { args: %w(headless disable-gpu) }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: capabilities)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :headless_chrome  # add more here
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

And here is the custom code handling capture screenshot and save web page:

```
# Take screenshot for every feature test failed
def file_path(example, filetype)
  meta = example.metadata
  name = "feature-#{File.basename(meta[:file_path])}-line:#{meta[:line_number]}.#{filetype}"
  screenshot_root_path = ENV["CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS"] || Rails.root.join("tmp", "capybara")
  screenshot_path = [screenshot_root_path, 'feature_tests', name].join("/")

  puts  "Screenshot Taken: #{screenshot_path}\n"
  screenshot_path
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :type => :feature) do
    Capybara.page.current_window.resize_to(1024, 768)
  end

  config.after(:each, :type => :feature) do |example|
    if example.exception
      page.save_screenshot(file_path(example, 'png'), full: true)
      save_page(file_path(example, 'html'))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your registered drivers have exactly the same as the defaults provided by Capybara, so you should just be able to set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome` or `Capybara.javascript_driver=:selenium_chrome_headless` and not need to register your own drivers- Also if you have required `capybara/rspec`, it will automatically switch `current_driver` between default and javascript based on metadata.  If you just want to always use the JS driver then set `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome`, etc.  You really should never manually be setting `current_driver` when testing an app.

Comment: Additionally, you can just set `Capybara.save_path` to the base where you want and then just call `page.save_screenshot(<calculate file name from 
 example>, full:true)` and  `page.save_page(<calculate file name from example>)` instead of needing to calculate the path everytime you take a screenshot

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I don't know why but if I don't set `Capybara.current_driver=:selenium_chrome` or anything, Capybara won't get capture image.

Comment: did you require capybara/rspec ? And did you set `default_driver` (if you want all feature tests run with a specific driver?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I also try save_path method as you said, but it doesn't work. Please take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/g4N3YyQy

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work” - it raises an error, or just nothing happens?

Comment: On my mac. it will print to console this line (if success, it will not). "Capybara::Driver::Base#save_screenshot". And there are not images/files generated in directory. If I run on CircleCI, I will have problem " Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:"

Comment: As you see that I want to run all feature tests with same driver only. But maybe I have configured "something" wrong, so I must set current_driver so that capybara can capture screenshot.

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing, those errors have to have more than just that - "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:" doesn't tell anything.  You're probably running an old version of Capybara and/or selenium - although if you have it working go with it.

Comment: Basically - https://pastebin.com/PAPnJ1uY - should be all you need to do, assuming you're using current releases of things.

Comment: In the test, did you add `:js` ?